# jQuery :: how to raise an event while loading a new page in div

Tags: jquery

I have 2 pages in asp.net. parent.aspx and child.aspx. There is a hyperlink on parent.aspx which loads child.aspx in a div. This loading is done using jquery's load method. Child.aspx has a code something like

```
  $(".lnkButton").click(function() 
  { 
         /* code */
  }
```

Now my problem is - whenever I will load child.aspx page from parent.aspx, I want to call specific event from child.aspx. How can I do this ?

Comment: how do you child page? are you using jquery load?

Comment: With POST/GET function of jquery. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: if you are using jquery you know when page load complete in callback

Comment: Hi Sushil, I am loading page using jquery load method. page load complete doesnt call another page's event.

Comment: Hey sushil, my code worked as you suggested. thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick your target element and trigger the event on it like so:

```
$(function(){  //ready
  $(".lnkButton").click(function() { 
    $('.childDiv').load('child.aspx',function(){ //load complete
      $('#parentDiv').trigger('click');  //replace 'click' with your event
    });
  });
});
```